# can i change resolution of video file using zenity with xrandr or encode

Tags: bash, zenity

```
#!/bin/bash 
option (){
MENU=("Resolution: $RES"
"File: $FILE"
"Play"
"Help"
"Version"
"End")
OPTION=$(zenity --list --column=Menu "${MENU[@]}" --width 300 -- 
height 250) 
while [ "$OPTION" != "End" ]
do

case $OPTION in
"Resolution: "*) RES=$(zenity --width="480" --height="480" --title 
"Resolution choice" -- 
list --separator=" " --column="Choose Video Resolution" "320x240" 
"720x400" | sed 's/ 
max//g')

if [ "$RES" == 720x400 ]
then
 xrandr --size 720x400 
elif [ "$RES" == 320x240 ]
then
 svcd_encode ()
{
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -target ntsc-svcd -sameq -hq -aspect 4:3 -y "$FILE"
}
vcd_encode ()
{
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -target ntsc-vcd -sameq -hq -aspect 4:3 -y "$FILE"
}
else
 zenity --error --title="error" --text="Niepoprawna rozdzielczosc"
exit 1
fi;;
"File: "*) FILE=$(zenity --file-selection);;
"Help "*) $(zenity --info --text "");;
"Version "*) $(zenity --info --text "");;
"End"*);;
 esac
 if [ "$OPTION" == "Play" ]
then
xdg-open "$FILE";
break; 
fi  
MENU=("Resolution: $RES"
"File: $FILE"
"Play"
"Help"
"Version"
"End)
OPTION=$(zenity --list --column=Menu "${MENU[@]}" --width 300 --height 250)
done 
}
$(option);
```

My script is supposed to change resolution of selected video file. How can I set selected resolution for video? Because these two ways, first with xrandr and second with encode do not work

Comment: There is too much and too many errors with the script you presented to give you a straight answer. Use [dynamic programming](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programowanie_dynamiczne) principle - split the problem to a sum of really small programs, start really small (and end big). For most obvious errors check https://shellcheck.net . Please edit the code and fix the additional newlines. Please fix unclosed `"`. Please edit the post and fix the indentation. What is `ffmpeg` here for? What is `xdg-open` here for? Why does the script do so much unrelated things?

Comment: My question is, is there a way to change resolution thats all. And those unrelated things are not a problem, also xdg-open is to open video file

Comment: So please remove them from the code snippet. Please post the _minimal_ [MCVE]

Comment: Ok I see you cant answer my question